# Retrieve last balance from update date using rank() and subquery in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, rank

I'm having troubles retrieving `balance` information from my table. Dataset looks like this:

```
| Name          | Last Name     | Balance | Update Date |
+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+
| John          | Doe           | $1600   | 2017-01-01  |
| John          | Doe           |   $12   | 2017-01-02  |
| John          | Doe           |    $1   | 2017-01-03  |
| John          | Doe           |   $16   | 2017-01-04  |
| John          | Doe           |   $16   | 2017-01-05  |
| John          | Doe           |   $16   | 2017-01-06  |
```

The task is to get most recent `Balance` with `Update Date`, but if same `Balance` is the same for several days, then in that case we need to get first `Update Date` with this `Balance`, so in that case, we need the following result:

```
| Name          | Last Name     | Balance | Update Date |
+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+
| John          | Doe           |   $16   | 2017-01-04  |
```

I tried to use my query:

```
select 
    a.name,
    a.last_name,
    a.balance,
    a.update_date
from
    (select
        name,
        last_name,
        balance,
        update_date,
        rank () over (partition by name, last_name order by update_date desc) top
    from
        customer_balance) a
where
    a.top = 1
```

but it obviously returns:

```
| Name          | Last Name     | Balance | Update Date |
+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------+
| John          | Doe           |   $16   | 2017-01-06  |
```

I'm not sure how to modify it to get desired result. Please note that I have limited access so no temp tables, functions or anything like that is allowed. Just plain selects, nothing fancy.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209986/oracle-sql-identify-sequential-value-ranges) to find the group of rows with the same balance that contains the latest update_date row (the difference between the rows at the top of the whole dataset and the latest balance will be 0) and then a group by to pick the earliest update_date, like so:

```
WITH customer_balance AS (SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 1600 balance, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 12 balance, to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 1 balance, to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('06/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 1600 balance, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 12 balance, to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 1 balance, to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 15 balance, to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('06/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe2' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('07/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 1600 balance, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 12 balance, to_date('02/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 1 balance, to_date('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('04/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('05/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 16 balance, to_date('06/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'John' first_name, 'Doe3' last_name, 17 balance, to_date('07/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') update_date FROM dual)
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       balance,
       min(update_date) update_date
FROM   (SELECT first_name,
               last_name,
               balance,
               update_date,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name ORDER BY update_date DESC) -- row number across the entire dataset (i.e. for each first_name and last_name)
                 - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name, balance ORDER BY update_date DESC) grp -- row number across each balance in the entire dataset.
        FROM   customer_balance)
WHERE  grp = 0
GROUP BY first_name,
         last_name,
         balance;

FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME    BALANCE UPDATE_DATE
---------- --------- ---------- -----------
John       Doe               16 04/01/2017
John       Doe2              16 06/01/2017
John       Doe3              17 07/01/2017
```

I've provided 3 scenarios:

1. Where the latest rows are for the same balance but that balance doesn't occur earlier in the dataset (i.e. your original dataset)
2. The latest rows are for the same balance but that balance occurs earlier in the dataset
3. The latest row has a different balance to the previous row.

Comment: @KaushikNayak your answer was valid too, except you were missing the correlation between the subquery and the main query - i.e. you should have been finding the max(update_date) for each name and last_name, rather than across the entire table. It would be interesting to compare both answers, as one may be more performant than the other, especially if there's an index on the first_name, last_name and update_date. (Commenting on my answer since you deleted yours before I could press send!)

Comment: Thanks Boneist. I realized it and will undelete it soon with the changes.

Comment: Apparently my original solution (even with correlation )does not work for certain scenarios and when I  modified it slightly to get the correct result, it ended up being a variation of Tabibitosan. So, I think it may not be more performant than this.

Comment: @KaushikNayak that’s a shame 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this query

```
WITH bal AS
  (SELECT 'John' first_name,
                 'Doe' last_name,
                       1600 balance,
                       to_date('20170101', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    12 balance,
                    to_date('20170102', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    1 balance,
                    to_date('20170103', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    16 balance,
                    to_date('20170104', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    16 balance,
                    to_date('20170105', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    16 balance,
                    to_date('20170106', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Doe',
                    328 balance,
                    to_date('20170107', 'YYYYMMDD') update_date
   FROM dual) -- The main query

SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT bal.*,
          LAG(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY first_name, last_name
                            ORDER BY update_date)prev_balance
   FROM bal )
WHERE prev_balance IS NULL
  OR balance != prev_balance
```

In the first step we get the previous balance.
At the second one we remove all lines where previous balance equals current one.
BTW sorry for the layout I answered from my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write out a tested solution, but the analytic function  `lead()` and `lag()` are intended for this:

```
select name, last_name, balance, update_date
  from (select name,
               last_name,
               balance,
               update_date,
               lead(balance) over (partition by first_name, last_name
                                      order by update_date) 
                 as next_balance
         where balance = :target_balance
         order by update_date
       )
 where balance <> next_balance
   and rownum = 1
```