# Fetching Specific Group of Rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with 'Name', 'Flag' and some other columns. I want to select specific group of rows from table. Data is already sorted based on another time-stamp column.

```
 Name          Flag
------        ------
  A             D
  B             D
  C             D
  D             I
  E             I
  D             D
  E             D
  B             I
  D             I
  F             I
```

I want to fetch 1st set of 'D' Flag and last set of 'I' flag. Is it possible in `SQL` (only select statement, not `PL/SQL`) somehow?

Desired Output:

```
 Name          Flag
------        ------
  A             D
  B             D
  C             D
  B             I
  D             I
  F             I
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first set" or "last set", unless the table has a row that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no "first" or "last", unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Note that this applies to both SQL queries and to PL/SQL code.  Of course, you specify that you have two columns, so no such column exists in your data.

But let me assume that you do have one.  If so, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.flag = 'D' and
       t.orderingcol < (select min(t2.orderingcol) from t t2 where t2.flag <> 'D'
      ) or
      (t.flag = 'I' and
       t.orderingcol > (select max(t2.orderingcol) from t t2 where t2.flag <> 'I'
      )
order by t.orderingcol;
```

Comment: Nice trick; though could be an issue if there were a D after the last I, or an I before the first D (or some other char at either end)... It's not stated whether that's possible.

Comment: I have updated the missing info. Thanks for pointing it out. But as said by John, there may be 'I' set in the beginning or 'D' in the end. In such case this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of column that determines the ordering of the result set (e.g. the id column in my query below), this is easy enough to do with a technique known as [Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210767/4479309):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'A' NAME, 'D' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 'B' NAME, 'D' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, 'C' NAME, 'D' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, 'D' NAME, 'I' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 5 ID, 'E' NAME, 'I' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6 ID, 'D' NAME, 'D' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 7 ID, 'E' NAME, 'D' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 8 ID, 'B' NAME, 'I' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9 ID, 'D' NAME, 'I' flag FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10 ID, 'F' NAME, 'I' flag FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       flag
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               NAME,
               flag,
               grp,
               MIN(CASE WHEN flag = 'D' THEN grp END) OVER (PARTITION BY flag) min_d_grp,
               MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'I' THEN grp END) OVER (PARTITION BY flag) max_i_grp
        FROM   (SELECT ID,
                       NAME,
                       flag,
                       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY ID) grp
                FROM   sample_data
                WHERE  flag IN ('D', 'I')))
WHERE  (flag = 'D' AND grp = min_d_grp)
OR     (flag = 'I' AND grp = max_i_grp)
ORDER BY id;

        ID NAME FLAG
---------- ---- ----
         1 A    D
         3 C    D
         2 B    D
         9 D    I
         8 B    I
        10 F    I
```

This query uses the tabibitosan method to generate an additional "grp" column, which you can then use to find the lowest number for the D flag rows and the highest for the I flag rows.

ETA: This may or may not perform better than Gordon's answer, but I would recommend you test both answers to see which works better for your tables/indexes/data etc.