# Querying database for rows until value change

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to execute a query (an Oracle Select) to get rows until a value of a specific column is changing without knowing this value

Let's say that we have following table:

```
1 - AAAA - kkkk
2 - BBBB - kkkk
3 - CCCC - kkkk
4 - DDDD - kkkk
5 - EEEE - xxxx
6 - FFFF - xxxx
```

Focusing on third column, I need to get only rows 1,2,3,4 (because for rows 5 and 6 third the value of the column changes). I don't know in advance the values kkkk and xxxx so that I cannot implement a specific and condition.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there only 2 possible values for the third column ? How to determine wich one is the "default" value, the minimal id ?

Comment: Maybe you should look into triggers for that effect - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Comment: Hello, no we can have more than 2 values for third column. The "default" value is the one of the first row, I know how to order the query.

Comment: How do you decide the order - based on the first column? Does that always start with 1 and has contiguous values (no gaps)?

Answer (score 3):

Use a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb923/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2 , col3 ) As
SELECT 1, 'AAAA', 'kkkk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BBBB', 'kkkk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CCCC', 'kkkk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'DDDD', 'kkkk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'EEEE', 'xxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'FFFF', 'xxxx' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH col1 = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR col1 + 1 = col1
       AND PRIOR col3 = col3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb923/1/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|------|------|------|
|    1 | AAAA | kkkk |
|    2 | BBBB | kkkk |
|    3 | CCCC | kkkk |
|    4 | DDDD | kkkk |
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use [Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210767/4479309), like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 col1, 'AAAA' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 col1, 'BBBB' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 col1, 'CCCC' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 col1, 'DDDD' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 col1, 'EEEE' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 col1, 'FFFF' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col1) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col3 ORDER BY col1) grp
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  grp = 0;

      COL1 COL2 COL3
---------- ---- ----
         1 AAAA kkkk
         2 BBBB kkkk
         3 CCCC kkkk
         4 DDDD kkkk
```

Example with the second row being different to the first:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 col1, 'AAAA' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 col1, 'BBBB' col2, 'aaaa' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 col1, 'CCCC' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 col1, 'DDDD' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 col1, 'EEEE' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 col1, 'FFFF' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col1) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col3 ORDER BY col1) grp
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  grp = 0;

      COL1 COL2 COL3
---------- ---- ----
         1 AAAA kkkk
```

I suggest you test all the solutions you're given to work out which is more performant for your data.

---

ETA: If, in your actual data, you have groups that you wish to apply this separately, you just need to add the relevant column(s) into the PARTITION BY clauses of the two row_number() analytic functions, e.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 id, 1 col1, 'AAAA' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 id, 2 col1, 'BBBB' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 id, 3 col1, 'CCCC' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 id, 4 col1, 'DDDD' col2, 'kkkk' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 id, 5 col1, 'EEEE' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 id, 6 col1, 'FFFF' col2, 'xxxx' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 id, 7 col1, 'GGGG' col2, 'aaaa' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 id, 8 col1, 'HHHH' col2, 'cccc' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 id, 9 col1, 'IIII' col2, 'bbbb' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 id, 10 col1, 'JJJJ' col2, 'cccc' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 id, 11 col1, 'KKKK' col2, 'aaaa' col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 id, 12 col1, 'LLLL' col2, 'cccc' col3 FROM DUAL)
SELECT id,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   (SELECT id,
               col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col1) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id, col3 ORDER BY col1) grp
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  grp = 0
ORDER BY ID, col1;

        ID       COL1 COL2 COL3
---------- ---------- ---- ----
         1          1 AAAA kkkk
         1          2 BBBB kkkk
         1          3 CCCC kkkk
         1          4 DDDD kkkk
         2          7 GGGG aaaa
         3          8 HHHH cccc
         3         10 JJJJ cccc
         3         12 LLLL cccc
```

Answer (score 3):

One more to compare the performance for, using a recursive CTE:

```
with r (col1, col2, col3) as (
  select col1, col2, col3
  from your_table
  where col1 = 1
  union all
  select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
  from r
  join your_table t on t.col1 = r.col1 + 1 and t.col3 = r.col3
)
select * from r
order by col1;

      COL1 COL2 COL3
---------- ---- ----
         1 AAAA kkkk
         2 BBBB kkkk
         3 CCCC kkkk
         4 DDDD kkkk
```

This is basically equivalent to @MTO's hierarchical query, it's just a different way of achieving that. As @Boneist said, sompare them all and see what is most appropriate for your real scenario.

Both of these assume that the `col1` values start at 1 and are contiguous, which is what you've shown in the sample data. If that isn't the case then it will be a bit more complicated with this sort of approach; but the Tabibitosan method will work anyway.