# Oracle - Get min & max date from group of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Initial data :

```
select t.AGENHI, t.TACTHI, t.DTEFHI, t.DTFIHI            
      from mytable t
      where agenhi = '81000040' ;

AGENHI      TACTHI   DTEFHI     DTFIHI            
81000040    1        24/02/92   08/03/92
81000040    1        09/03/92   28/02/93
81000040    1        01/03/93   31/05/97
81000040    0,8      01/06/97   31/12/97
81000040    1        01/01/98   31/12/98
81000040    1        01/01/99
```

Using this query  :

```
SELECT AGENHI, 
DECODE(TACTHI, 0.05, '005', 0.07, '007', 0.1, '010', 0.137, '013', 0.15, 
'015', 0.2, '020', 0.21, '021', 0.23, '023', 0.25, '025', 0.3, '030', 
0.34, '034', 0.4, '040', 0.45, '045', 0.5, '050', 0.6, '060', 0.63, 
'063',0.7, '070', 0.75, '075', 0.8,'080', 0.84, '084',0.9, '090', 1, '100', 
TACTHI) as QUOTITE,
dtefhi as START_DATE,
DECODE(LEAD (DTFIHI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DTFIHI NULLS LAST) ,null, 
to_date('31122099','ddmmyyyy'), LEAD (DTFIHI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DTFIHI NULLS 
LAST)) AS END_DATE
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE AGENHI = '81000040' AND DTFIHI IS NOT NULL;
```

I get :

```
AGENHI      QUOTITE     START_DATE    END_DATE
81000040    100         08/03/92      28/02/93
81000040    100         28/02/93      31/05/97
81000040    100         31/05/97      31/12/97
81000040    080         31/12/97      31/12/98
81000040    100         31/12/98      31/12/99
```

But i need to group "QUOTITE" when next rows is the same and display the start date of the first row and the date of last rows.

Expected result :

```
AGENHI      QUOTITE     START_DATE    END_DATE
81000040    100         24/02/92      31/12/97
81000040    080         01/06/97      31/12/98
81000040    100         01/01/98      31/12/99
```

Solution provided by gordon :

select agenhi, tacthi, min(dtfihi) as start_date,
       lead(max(dtfihi)) over (partition by agenhi, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by max(dtfihi)) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by agenhi order by dtfihi) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by agenhi, tacthi order by dtfihi) as seqnum_2
      from HIA@CHRONOS_TO_S2.WORLD t
      where agenhi = '81000040' and dtfihi IS NOT NULL
     ) t
group by agenhi, (seqnum - seqnum_2), tacthi;

Result :

```
81000040    1   08/03/92   null 
81000040    1   31/12/98   null   
81000040    0,8 31/12/97   null
```

How can i get the end_date ? 
I will look if i found the solution thank you !

Comment: This kind of problem is called gaps and islands. There are many requests on this on SO you can look up. You'll have to get `quotite` first, then subtract `row_number() over (partition by quotite order by dtfihi)` from `row_number() over (order by dtfihi)` to get a group key. Then aggregate getting min and max date per group key. At last use `LEAD` to adjust the end dates.

Answer (score 2):

You have a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would start with the original data, so something like this:

```
select agenhi, tacthi, min(dtfihi) as start_date,
       lead(min(dtfihi)) over (partition by agenhi order by min(dtfihi)) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by agenhi, order by dtfihi) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by agenhi, tacthi order by dtfihi) as seqnum_2
      from mytable t
      where agenhi = '81000040' an dtfihi IS NOT NULL
     ) t
group by agenhi, (seqnum - seqnum_2), tacthi;
```

You can add the `decode()` logic (which I would write as a `case` expression), but it doesn't really change the solution.

Comment: Just to add (for the OP): The technique of finding the difference between the row number of the main group (seqnum) and the row number of the sub-group (seqnum_2) that Gordon has demonstrated in their answer is known as [Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210767/4479309). I would do the minus in the subquery where the row_numbers are generated, rather than outside of the query since it means less typing in the outer query, but that's personal preference.

Comment: @Boneist . . . I've taking to leaving the `row_numbers()` separated in the subquery, so people can see what they look like.  I find it hard to explain why the difference identifies the groups.  But when you see what happens, most people have an "aha" moment.

Comment: Thank you for your help gordon !

I have only null values for end_date ... can you help me again ? :)

Comment: @Beanl . . . The group logic was not correct in the `partition by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, I figured it was something like that. I was just attempting to provide more info to the OP

Comment: @Beanl just change the lead to: `lead(min(dtfihi), 1, to_date(‘31/12/2099’, ‘dd/mm/yyyy’))`; that allows you to put a default value when no next row is found.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i updated the initial data in my post, it was missing the DTFIHI column

Answer (score 0):

@Boneist , @GordonLinoff Thank you again for your help.

```
select 
agenhi, 
DECODE(TACTHI, 0.05, '005', 0.07, '007', 0.1, '010', 0.137, '013', 0.15, '015', 0.2, '020', 0.21, '021', 0.23, '023', 0.25, '025', 0.3, '030', 
0.34, '034', 0.4, '040', 0.45, '045', 0.5, '050', 0.6, '060', 0.63, '063',0.7, '070', 0.75, '075', 0.8,'080', 0.84, '084',0.9, '090', 1, '100', TACTHI) as QUOTITECPAGE,  
min(dtefhi) as start_date,
nvl(lead(min(dtfihi)) over (partition by agenhi order by min(dtfihi)), 
to_date('31122099','ddmmyyyy')) as end_date
from (select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by agenhi order by dtfihi) as seqnum,
         row_number() over (partition by agenhi, tacthi order by dtefhi) as seqnum_2
  from HIA@CHRONOS_TO_S2.WORLD t
  where agenhi = '81000040' order by DTEFHI
 ) t
 group by agenhi, (seqnum - seqnum_2), tacthi;
```