# SQL query to interpolate between values

Tags: sql, oracle

I intend to interpolate (**linear interpolation**) between values in a column and insert that into a new column using a SQL query.
Based on my search online, I suspect LEAD analytic function could be useful.
I am new to writing SQL queries. So, any insights on how it can be achieved will be quite helpful.

The sample data set is as described:

```
Emp  Test_date  Value
---  ---------  -----
A    1/1/2001   null
A    1/2/2001   100
A    1/3/2001   null
A    1/4/2001   80
A    1/5/2001   null
A    1/6/2001   null
A    1/7/2001   75
```

The idea is to get a fourth column that has values as:

```
null
100
interpolatedValue1
80
interpolatedValue2
interpolatedValue3
75
```

*Interpolatedvalue1* would be an interpolated value between **100** and **80**,

*Interpolatedvalue2* would be a linearly interpolated value between **80** and **75**.

*InterpolatedValue3* would be a linearly interpolated value between **Interpolatedvalue2** and **75**

***Here's how a simple linear interpolation works:***

Given two points (**V1** at **D1**), (**V3** at **D3**). What would be the value ***V2*** at **D2**?

**(V3-V1)/(D3-D1) * (D2-D1) + V1**

Comment: So we have the freedom to also invent the interpolate formula which you need to use? This is not how stackoverflow works

Comment: This is a "Gaps & Islands" problem. Search for its solution first. Once you get that detection sorted out then the interpolation will be simpler to achieve.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thnx for the note sir. It is linear interpolation.

Comment: What does "InterpolatedValue" mean? I think this is above my paygrade. What values would YOU put in there...?

Comment: @JNevill pardon my naivety. Updated the question. Interpolatedvalue1 would be an interpolated value between 100 and 80, interpolatedvalue2 and interpolatedvalue3 would be linearly interpolated values between 80 and 75.

Comment: I think we should voteclose this question as we tryed for a number of times to get expected results and or the formula.. the topicstarter is keeping the answer open with question marks with his comments and not making anny attemp to explain it better

Comment: @RaymondNijland I updated the question and added additional details.

Comment: The confusion, @user11397513, is that most of us here have no idea what interpolation is, so you are stuck waiting for both an expert in SQL and an expert in statistics or whatever field it is where "interpolation" is a known and understood term. It *may* help, in the future (Although it didn't here) to share how you would do that math if you had to do this exercise by hand. Thankfully Gordon Linoff is here to save the day :)

Comment: Ok last attempt which formula should be used to calculate the number between 80 and 90 and what should be the result.. Same goes for the other values. We need facts to answer a question not open stuff which can be everything

Comment: Well @JNevill if mine math is right you cant directly linear interpolate two unknown points between two known points so yes how would  you formulate that. Unless you sample it multiple times i geuss interpolate one point between the two values and interpolate twice with the new found point

Comment: Do any of [the built-in linear regression functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGR_-Linear-Regression-Functions.html) do what you need?

Comment: The answer you have accepted gives the same value for `interpolatedvalue2`  and `interpolatedvalue3`  - both 77.5. Is that what you wanted, or should they be 76.666 and 78.333? Or something else? I'm not sure why you've refused to give actual expected values in your question, it would have made things much clearer.

Comment: @AlexPoole Very valid point!!! Actually you are absolutely right. The expected answer should 76.66 and then 78.33!!

Comment: @AlexPoole it becomes a bit more complicated  now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can probably be simplified a bit but gets the answer you wanted, I believe. The slightly tricky bit is getting both the number of days between not-null values (i.e. the size of the gap you're filling) and then the position within that gap:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (emp, test_date, value) as (
            select 'A', date '2001-01-01', null from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-02', 100 from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-03', null from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-04', 80 from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-05', null from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-06', null from dual
  union all select 'A', date '2001-01-07', 75 from dual
)
-- actual query
select emp, test_date, value,
  coalesce(value,
    (next_value - prev_value) -- v3-v1
    / (count(*) over (partition by grp) + 1) -- d3-d1
    * row_number() over (partition by grp order by test_date desc) -- d2-d1, indirectly
    + prev_value -- v1
  ) as interpolated
from (
  select emp, test_date, value,
    last_value(value ignore nulls)
      over (partition by emp order by test_date) as prev_value,
    first_value(value ignore nulls)
      over (partition by emp order by test_date range between current row and unbounded following) as next_value,
    row_number() over (partition by emp order by test_date) -
      row_number() over (partition by emp order by case when value is null then 1 else 0 end, test_date) as grp
  from your_table
)
order by test_date;
```

```
E TEST_DATE       VALUE INTERPOLATED
- ---------- ---------- ------------
A 2001-01-01                        
A 2001-01-02        100          100
A 2001-01-03                      90
A 2001-01-04         80           80
A 2001-01-05              76.6666667
A 2001-01-06              78.3333333
A 2001-01-07         75           75
```

I've used `last_value` and `first_value` instead of `lead` and `lag`, but either works. (Lead/lag might be faster on a large data set I suppose). The `grp` calculation is [Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209986/oracle-sql-identify-sequential-value-ranges/48210767#48210767).

Comment: This is super! Works great. I will run it on a large dataset to test the duration of the calculation.

Comment: Should the 5th day's result be 78.333, and the 6th 76.666?  The two non interpolated data are 80 and ending with the smaller 75. Thus the linear progression between the two known dates is a negative slope. The result from the sample code is not working for the gap between the 2015-01-05 and 2015-01-07 dates. If that can be corrected this is a great solution.

Comment: @cmill - yes, probably; not sure what the original asker wanted. But you can reverse those just by changing 'desc' to 'asc' (or removing it) - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=012034a2f57881f2400fc48ac6301d07).

Comment: @Alex Poole Your suggestion works.  I will try to benefit from your full SQL fiddle statements.  They are a little above my current capability.  I can explain interpolation but people can google that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `lag(ignore nulls)`.  You don't specify how to do the interpolation, but a linear interpolation would be:

```
select emp, test_date,
       coalesce(test_value,
                ( next_tv * (next_td - test_date) +
                  prev_tv * (test_date - prev_td)
                ) / (next_td - prev_td)
               ) as imputed_value
from (select t.*,
             lag(test_value ignore nulls) over (partition by emp order by test_date) as prev_tv,
             lag(case when test_value is not null then test_date end ignore nulls) over (partition by emp order by test_date) as prev_td,
             lead(test_value ignore nulls) over (partition by emp order by test_date) as next_tv,
             lead(case when test_value is not null then test_date end ignore nulls) over (partition by emp order by test_date) as next_td
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I don't this works, since the dates are never null. The interpolated value for 1/5/2001 would be calculated based on the dates 1/4/2001 and 1/6/2001, not 1/4/2001 and 1/7/2001

Comment: @titusAdam . . . Good observation.  That should be a test on `test_value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

here a fix for SQL Impala with ASC interpolation

```
select emp, test_date, value,
  coalesce(value,
    (next_value - prev_value) -- v3-v1
    / (count(*) over (partition by grp) + 1) -- d3-d1
    * row_number() over (partition by grp order by test_date desc) -- d2-d1, indirectly
    + prev_value -- v1
  ) as interpolated
from (
  select emp, test_date, value,
    last_value(value ignore nulls)
      over (partition by emp order by test_date) as prev_value,
    first_value(value ignore nulls)
      over (partition by emp order by test_date range between current row and unbounded following) as next_value,
    row_number() over (partition by emp order by test_date) -
      row_number() over (partition by emp order by case when value is null then 1 else 0 end, test_date) as grp
  from test.table
) t

order by test_date
```