# Update a column value within a SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, impala, analytic-functions

I have a complicated SQL question.

Can we update a column within a SELECT query? Example:

Consider this table:

```
    |ID   |SeenAt  |
    ----------------
    |1    |20      |
    |1    |21      |
    |1    |22      |
    |2    |70      |
    |2    |80      |
```

I want a SELECT Query that gives for each ID when was it seen for the first time. And when did it seen 'again':

```
    |ID   |Start  |End  |
    ---------------------
    |1    |20     |21   |
    |1    |20     |22   |
    |1    |20     |22   |
    |2    |70     |80   |
    |2    |70     |80   |
```

First, both columns `Start` and `End` would have the same value, but when a second row with the same `ID` is seen we need to update its predecessor to give `End` the new `SeenAt` value. 
I succeeded to create the `Start` column, I give the minimum `SeenAt` value per `ID` to all IDs. But I can't find a way to update the `End` column everytime.

Don't mind the doubles, I have other columns that change in every new row

Also, I am working in Impala but I can use Oracle.

I hope that I have been clear enough. Thank you

Comment: You need the `min()` and `max()` analytic functions, by the looks of it. Or possibly the [tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210767/4479309) method, if you're looking for consecutive groups of the id (e.g. what if a new row for id = 1 was added with a seenat of 30? Would that be a group on its own, or would it belong with the first group, with min = 20 and max = 30?

Comment: are you sure about the values in the output for `End`?I suppose they should be `20,21,22,70,80`,aren't they?

Comment: End should contain the start value of the new row with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lead()` and `nvl()`:

```
select id, min(seenat) over (partition by id) seen_start,
       nvl(lead(seenat) over (partition by id order by seenat), seenat) seen_end
  from t
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=acafecd334f67c822f469054a1cdf69b)</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

Start is easy just the `MIN` of the `GROUP`

End you need to find the MIN after the `SeenAt` and in case you don't find it then the current `SeenAt`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5712/13)**

```
SELECT "ID", 
        (SELECT MIN("SeenAt")
         FROM Table1 t2
         WHERE t1."ID" = t2."ID") as "Start",
        COALESCE(
                 (SELECT MIN("SeenAt")
                  FROM Table1 t2
                  WHERE t1."ID" = t2."ID"
                  AND t1."SeenAt" < t2."SeenAt")
                 , t1."SeenAt"
                ) as End

FROM Table1 t1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | START | END |
|----|-------|-----|
|  1 |    20 |  21 |
|  1 |    20 |  22 |
|  1 |    20 |  22 |
|  2 |    70 |  80 |
|  2 |    70 |  80 |
```

Answer (score 1):

you seem to need `min()` analytic function with a `self-join`:

```
select distinct t1.ID,
       min(t1.SeenAt) over (partition by t1.ID order by t1.ID) as "Start",
       t2.SeenAt as "End"
  from tab t1
  join tab t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.SeenAt<=t2.SeenAt
 order by t2.SeenAt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e859604357e074969dafa1a243ec9b1e)</kbd>