# Stale Last Change Date

Tags: oracle

I want to fill date column with the date based upon the price history, so for example: if price is same for 10 days then, I want to show the initial date when price changed in for all 10 days.

Expected Output (Last_Change_Date)
ORACLE DB

```
Last_Change_Date           Effective_Date           Current_Value
01/01/2019                 01/01/2019                100
01/01/2019                 01/02/2019                100
01/01/2019                 01/03/2019                100
01/01/2019                 01/04/2019                100
01/05/2019                 01/05/2019                120
01/05/2019                 01/06/2019                120
01/05/2019                 01/07/2019                120
```

Comment: Please provide the actual table DDL and sample data. Based on the only output, How we will be able to write the query for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210767/4479309), like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 100 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('02/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 100 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('03/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 100 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('04/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 100 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('05/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 120 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('06/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 120 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('07/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 120 current_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('08/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') effective_date, 100 current_value FROM dual),
    tabibitosan AS (SELECT effective_date,
                           current_value,
                           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY effective_date)
                             - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY current_value ORDER BY effective_date) grp
                    FROM   your_table)
SELECT MIN(effective_date) OVER (PARTITION BY current_value, grp) last_change_date,
       effective_date,
       current_value
FROM   tabibitosan
ORDER BY effective_date;

LAST_CHANGE_DATE EFFECTIVE_DATE CURRENT_VALUE
---------------- -------------- -------------
01/01/2019       01/01/2019               100
01/01/2019       02/01/2019               100
01/01/2019       03/01/2019               100
01/01/2019       04/01/2019               100
05/01/2019       05/01/2019               120
05/01/2019       06/01/2019               120
05/01/2019       07/01/2019               120
08/01/2019       08/01/2019               100
```

I say to use the tabibitosan method, since your price may change up and back down (as per the extra row I added to your sample data). If your price can only ever increase, then you could just use the `min(effective_date)` analytic function on your table directly.

Answer (score 0):

Compare current value with previous row using `lag` and assign `null` when it was the same, `effective_date` otherwise. Then use `last_value()` to fill null values.

```
select effective_date, current_value, 
       last_value(ldt ignore nulls) over (order by effective_date) last_change
  from (select effective_date, current_value, 
               case current_value when lag(current_value) over (order by effective_date) 
                    then null else effective_date 
               end ldt 
          from t)
```

**<sup>[dfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98be88f53c071dc178d50bfad3ecbe88)</sup>**